# how can i get print selected combo item?

Tags: java, combobox, selecteditem

I want to print which i select value in combobox.My code print to all combobox item.How can I do that?

```
      public void coursename(){
     Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
     session.beginTransaction();
     Query query= session.createQuery("select a.courseName  from Semester e inner join e.course as a"); 
   for (Iterator it = query.iterate(); it.hasNext();) {
       Object  row = (Object) it.next();
      combocourse.addItem(row);
     System.out.println(row);

     }        
       session.close();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

combocourse.getSelectedItem();

Comment: it didnt get selected value.what should i write instead of       "combocourse.addItem(row);"?